# Foreach over certain part of a loop

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

Let's say I have the following `String` array.

```
String[] arr = {"Index0", "Index1", "Index2", "Index3",..."Index n"};
```

I can iterate over the **entire** array using:

```
for (String eachElement : arr){
    //Do something
}
```

But what if I wanted to do a `foreach` over a certain part of the array.

I know that I can do something like this with a for loop:

```
int startingIndex = 1;
int endingIndex = 3;
for (int i = startingIndex; i < endingIndex; i++){
//Do something
}
```

Is there a way I could do something similar using `foreach` loop?

Comment: maybe it wasn't a good idea but you can use a temp array and put the indexes you want in that temp and do foreach loop on new array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use

```
for(String eachIndex : Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, startingIndex, endingIndex)){
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing to use **Java8** then you can use

```
Arrays.stream(arr, startingIndex, endingIndex).forEach(eachIndex->{ 
        //Do Something
});
```